# Hyperledger accessing transaction ID in invoke function

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

if I call Invoke of chain code, I get transaction ID in REST response. e.g.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "e00848bc-71c3-422f-b637-cbfc9d2e2042"
  },
  "id": 4
}
```

How can I access this transaction ID (e00848bc-71c3-422f-b637-cbfc9d2e2042 in above example) programatically in my invoke function of chaincode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access transaction ID in Invoke function using:

```
stub.GetTxID()
```

Comment: I don't see any GetTxID() method in shim.ChaincodeStubInterface. Am I missing anything?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go   line 50

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot. It got added in code on 8th Sept. Thanks a lot again...